# How to reverse a range of numbers

Tags: functions, arithmetic, inverse

if I have a range of floating point numbers, specifically this: `min: 0.5 max: 1.5` How do I reverse the order of a selected place in the range?

For instance if I pic `1.5` I would want my result to be `0.5`. `1` would get `1` (I think), `0.5` would get `1.5`, and any number in between would correspond to this reverse ordering.

Comment: The function you want is simply $f(x) = 2-x$, which is order reversing by construction (i.e., $x > y$ implies that $f(x) < f(y)$), and $f(0.5) = 1.5$, $f(1.5) = 0.5$, keeping you in the desired range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, that if you pick $x$ and $y$ is its *reverse*, then $x+y=2$ should hold. So, you can calculate the reverse by
$$f(x)=2-x$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the vector storing the numbers be $v$. Then $v(1)=0.5$ and $v(n)=1.25$ where $n\times 1$ is the size of your vector. Then form a new vector $u$ of size $n\times 1$ such that $$u(i)=v(n+1-i)$$ then $u$ contains the numbers in reversed order.